# VirtualBox fails to start VM after upgrade from 6.1.26 to 6.1.28 with Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)

Tags: virtualbox

After many messages about the new 6.1.28 VirtualBox version I decided to upgrade. Then I started my VM and was greeted with the following error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine VMName.

Call to NEMR0InitVMPart2 failed: VERR_NEM_INIT_FAILED (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Rebooted Windows 10 but the same error persisted. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [a post](https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/qbkx4e/comment/hhtwx5w/) reinforced my suspicion that it was the upgrade. Indeed after downgrading back to 6.1.26 (I still had the original download for that version but you can get it from the archive) my virtual machine started just fine.

Not the ideal solution but for now I don't want to waste time with an upgrade that breaks things. If a future version comes up that does work after this error, would be happy to accept that answer.

**Update**: Just upgraded to Version *6.1.38 r153438 (Qt5.6.2)* and my VM started fine. Was forced to upgrade it because of the [Windows 11 update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5007125-compatibility-hold-when-you-upgrade-to-windows-11-with-oracle-virtualbox-installed-ea84b50c-77f5-473c-99a8-81c2b7b53d35):

> VirtualBox. Your PC requires the latest version of this app. Click
> Learn More for information on how to update this app.

Comment: Downgrading back to 6.1.26 helped me too