# VirtualBox VM fails with VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND when starting with bridged adapter on Win11

Tags: virtualbox, windows-11

Not sure what triggered this, but it started after I upgraded from 6.1.38 to 6.1.40. The error is similar on the GUI and commandline:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz' (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

**Host**: Windows 11

**Guest VM**: Ubuntu

Searched online and tried many things, including reinstalling the previous version. Now back on 6.1.40 since that didn't help. I noticed that the VM does start if I change the adapter to NAT, but I prefer bridged since it gets its own IP and makes life easier to SSH, etc.

One thing I noticed going to device manager, is that there are two "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" both showing an error:

```
Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware. The driver may be corrupted or missing. (Code 39)

The specified page protection was not valid.
```

But I am no longer using the host only adapter, only trying to get the bridged one working. Already disabled, then removed those adapters from device manager, but they came back after VirtualBox reinstallation, still broken. Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are using the latest version of VirtualBox and
Guest Additions.

Here is some advice :

1. Verify that the correct network adapter is selected in the
   VM Network Settings
2. In Device Manager, disable & enable the VirtualBox adapter
3. Update the VirtualBox network adapter driver :

   - Run Device Manager
   - Under Network adapters, right-click the VirtualBox adapter you used
   - Select "Update Driver"
   - Select "Browse my computer for drivers"
   - Click "Let me pick from a list of available drivers ..."
   - Select from the list the VirtualBox network adapter and click Next
   - After the driver is updated, start the VM and check if the
     error persists.

For more information see the article
[VirtualBox Failed to open-create the internal network](https://www.wintips.org/fix-virtualbox-failed-to-open-create-the-internal-network/).

Comment: Thanks, saw that article and tried all that, but didn't help. Driver wasn't fixed and issue persists.

Comment: Try to uninstall VirtualBox, remove the network adapters if they're left over, then reinstall VirtualBox. If nothing helps, uninstall and install version 6.1.38. I note that the latest VirtualBox version today is 7.0.4, so you could also give it a try before going backwards.

Comment: Version 7x wasn't showing up on  "check for updates", must be the major version change, thanks for letting me know. I have gone through this cycle many times: removed the "VirtualBox Host-only Network Adapters", uninstalled VirtualBox, reinstalled a different version: 6.1.38, 6.1.40 and now 7.0.4. The adapters come back with the same error, tried updating them, but Win11 tells me it's already the latest version. Not sure they're causing the issue, never checked them when all was working fine. Should have tried creating a restore point when all was good, at the moment there isn't one.

Comment: Also tried all the adapter types under "advanced", none of them fixed the issue.

Comment: Have you tried downgrading to version 6.1.38?

Comment: ... or have you recently upgraded to Windows 11?

Comment: I upgraded to Windows 11 almost a month ago, and [it was working fine](https://superuser.com/a/1684789/668905) until it wasn't. Yes, I did try downgrading to version 6.1.38. Ended up [doing a PC reset](https://superuser.com/a/1753970/668905), which fixed it, but wouldn't recommend it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you now on Windows 10?

Comment: The PC Reset keeps it on Windows 11, but it wipes out apps and settings, etc.

Comment: I hope it's not some installed app that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Go to Device Manager (right-click on the start menu).
2. Under "Network adapters," there are a bunch of "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #" items with a number after them. Right-click on each one with a yellow exclamation mark and click "uninstall device".
3. Restart your computer and try to start the VM again.

I also changed the adapter type from "PCI III" to "PCI II". I don't know if this changed anything.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this issue and solved it by uninstalling Virtualbox then reinstalling it, but running the installation with administrator privileges. After this the VM's loaded faultlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with both the the VirtualBox Ethernet driver and the VirtualBox USB driver failing to load on a Windows 11 host.

I found that disabling Windows 11 Memory Integrity allowed the drivers to load. That setting can be found at: Start | Windows Security | Device Security | Core Isolation | Memory Integrity.

Once I disabled Memory Integrity and rebooted Windows, the VirtualBox Ethernet and USB drivers loaded and functioned as expected. Even after subsequently enabling Memory Integrity and rebooting, both drivers continued to load properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed it for me on Win11. Checking the device manager while VirtualBox USB sharing is active, a "VirtualBox USB" device is shown with a non working driver. The error message gave a vague hint in the direction of a memory integrity violation. After disabling the Memory Integrity feature of the WIndows Security solved that.

Answer (score 0):

##### Undesirable Solution: Reset PC and Keep Personal Files

This can be done by going to *Settings > System > Recovery > Reset this PC*. I made sure to select "keep personal files" and even though I keep important files on OneDrive, I backed up critical files to a thumb drive. This reinstalls Windows 11.

Please Note: I *strongly discourage this option*. It was a *last resort* after trying everything I could think of, including multiple iterations of uninstalling and reinstalling different versions of VirtualBox. Best to try other things first, like [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1753798/668905) I upvoted.

Not only this is a lengthy process, I had to spend more than a day restoring my development environment, installing apps and fixing issues, adding Windows Mail accounts, lost my Opera bookmarks, etc. But I am happy to report that it works. VirtualBox now starts again with a bridged interface.

##### Create a Restore Point

In the past I have fixed weird Windows issues by enabling and creating a [restore point](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-system-restore-point-77e02e2a-3298-c869-9974-ef5658ea3be9), so you can roll back the system to another point in time. This can be done by going to Settings and searching for "restore point" in "Find a Setting" and choosing "Create a Restore Point". Or go to *Settings > System > About > System protection* (below Device specifications).

It's possible that I might have been able to fix it, if I had it enabled before. I've now enabled it and created one manual restore point right after I got VirtualBox working.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error in windows 11 .. solution is just go to the device manager
under network adapters find **virtual box host only adapter is installed** without any warnings. if you find so uninstall the driver and vm then reinstall the vm.
before that you have to update the wifi adapter from intel website
https://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/download/18649/intel-wireless-bluetooth-for-windows-10-and-windows-11.html

only after the update (driver), you can reinstall the vm. it will fix the issue.

Comment: Hello, that links to a bluetooth driver, not wi-fi, please correct it. Any context as to wy updating that helps would also be welcome.