# Any chance that Opera Bookmarks can be recovered after a Windows PC Reset?

Tags: windows, bookmarks, opera, system-restore

After I [reset my Windows PC](https://superuser.com/a/1753970/668905), choosing to keep my personal data, I realized that I totally forgot to backup my Opera bookmarks! Trust me, learned my lesson, now I have an Opera account to automatically sync them to the cloud.

But I noticed that Edge did keep some bookmarks, so I'm wondering, would there possibly be a way to restore, access or recover the original bookmarks (besides going back in time)? Wishful thinking, I know, but it wouldn't be the first time I learned something surprising, so thought I'd ask anyway. A solution would be insightful and most appreciated.

I tried copying the `AppData\Local\Opera Software\Opera Stable` folders "*Cache and System Cache*" under `Windows.old` to the current location (after a backup, not suggesting anyone to try it), but didn't seem to have made any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to copy the `AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable` folder from `Windows.old` (presumably a rename done by the Windows reset operation to preserve the previous installation) to its live location (`Windows`), **after** a backup *and* renaming the existing folder with Opera closed.

Not recommending anyone to do this, but happy to say that it works. Bookmarks restored!

Answer (score 0):

Anytime that you add a new bookmark, Opera writes a Bookmarks.bak file.  You can remove the .bak to restore your bookmarks.